# SQL format don't work

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i have a problem with my sql request probably a synthax problem, can u watch it? see the line:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT " . $fields . "FROM" . $table . "WHERE link =  " . $requestUrl);
```

i think "FROM" and "WHERE..." is not good, what is the exact synthax?

Comment: You should add the debug output of this SQL string.

Comment: requestUrl must be quoted. But you don't want to use string interpolation anyway, but prepared statements.

Comment: Compose the query in a PHP variable and `echo()` it. You will be able to find the issues yourself. If they are still not obvious then paste the query into a MySQL client, run it, fiddle with it until you make it work then apply the changes back to the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

$requestUrl must have been wrapped with single quotes and leave proper spaces in query

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table . " WHERE link =  '" . $requestUrl ."'";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: this don't resolve my problem, the problem is the synthax " FROM " " WHERE " is not recognized such as sql langage, it appears in "text color" in my editor, see my screen : http://postimg.org/image/aqtdzz8vt/

Comment: $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM   $table WHERE link =  '" . $requestUrl . "'"); <- Problem resolved